# What went wrong in my evaluation of this limit? $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1-\sqrt x}{(\cos^{-1} x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

My process:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-\sqrt x}{(\cos^{-1} x)^2} &=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1- x^2}{(\cos^{-1} x)^2(1+\sqrt x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(\sin(\cos^{-1}x))^2}{(\cos^{-1} x)^2(1+\sqrt x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

The answer is infact $\frac{1}{4}$ what went wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1 -\sqrt x = \frac{1-x}{1+\sqrt x} = \frac{1-x^2}{(1+x)(1+\sqrt x)}.$$

So you are missing a $1+x$ at the bottom.